# How to create only the outline border in html table without using any CSS?

Tags: html

I am creating a document.So I have to create an html table, but only with the outside border the catch is I can't use any *CSS*.

I have tried many things I have searched the internet and nothing showed up..

```
<table> width="60%" height=100% align="center" 
border="1px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">....Information...<table>
```

This is the table styling that i have done but if i show the border `( border="1px" )` the border is inside and outside like a regular table border but i need it to be only in the outside.

I expect the table border to be only outside but it's both inside and outside like the regular table border.Is there any way i can do this without using any CSS?

Comment: If you can't use CSS, you should remove the css tag..

Comment: You would have to use styling directly in the HTML of every single element in the table I suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without using css i guess this is the only way to show how want to see the table.

```
<table frame="box">
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question or even i can't explain it well enough to be understandable. I need the border to be shown only on the outside of the table not inside. I mean i don't want to see the lines between the rows and the columns.

Comment: I have update my answer. this will give you outer line for your table

Comment: please accept this answer if it meet your requirement

Answer (score 0):

then try this..

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;">
<table>..........</table>
</div>
```